# Orbits of Infinite Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

"Any $L^+G$-orbit in Gr is known to be an orbit of the form Oλ for some λ ∈ $X_*(T)$, and Oλ = Oμ iff λ and μ are conjugate by W   and the orbits form a finite stratification of each of the $Gr_i$."
who can prove this sentence? please tell me.

I also want to know the information $L^+T$-orbit in Gr and LN-orbit in Gr ,where T is max torus and N=[B,B],(B is a borel group )

Comment: Can you give a little more context, please?  Where are these statements from?  What exactly is the part that you are having difficulty with?


Comment: this sentence comes from“PERVERSE SHEAVES ON A LOOP
GROUP AND LANGLANDS’ DUALITY”

difficulty is the provement。

thank you！

Comment: Could you edit your question a little and include a link to that article.  Also, could you say whether or not you have read *Loop Groups* by Pressley and Segal as I suspect that the answer is in there.


Comment: This is the Bruhat decomposition for the affine Grassmannian, related to Birkhoff's theorem giving a BWB decomposition for loops.  It can, indeed, be found in Pressley-Segal, though I believe it is proved there only for GL(n).  Look also in Kumar's book.

Comment: thank you ， Andrew Stacey and  Michael Thaddeus 。I will read loop group

Comment: I find loop Grassmannian is simaler flag varieties 